# Deleting a pointer in destructor C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I am using a class from a library. Let it be A, and it has a character pointer "token"

My code:

```
void someFunction()
{
    A a;
    cout<<a.token;
    anotherFunction(a);
    cout<<a.token;  //  line 4: now token became invalid [1]
}

void anotherFunction(A copyOfA);
{
   //  doing something
}  //  on exit destructor of copyofA will be called
```

[1] Why did it become invalid: class A is as follows:

```
class A
{
    char *token;
    public:
    A()
    {
        token = GetRandomToken();   // GetRandomToken will return a 'new Char' array
    }
    ~A()
    {
        if(token != NULL)
        {
            delete[] token;    // it is A's responsibility to delete the memory it created
            token = NULL;
        }
    }
};
```

*in `anotherFunction` when the destructor of copyOfA is called  `token` got deleted.* So at line 4, token is invalid because both a.token and copyOfA.token both pointing to same address.

What is the solution, in following case:

case 1: `class A` is in a given library: So I can't modify it.

case 2: if I can modify `class A`: What will be the good way to handle this?

I know, if anotherFunction is called by passing reference, I won't have hit this problem. But what if I have to keep a copy of the object at some point?

Check sample code here: https://ideone.com/yZa4k4

Comment: `class A` does not follow the [rule of 3/5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You cannot copy it safely

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: You can use std:unique_ptr to hold only one copy of class A or std::shadred_ptr if class A is a sharable resource.

Comment: @UnholySheep: No, I am given this class (from library). I want to know if there is some work around, so I can use this class?

Comment: The only workaround is to never create a copy. You can only have a single instance and pass around references or pointers to it.

Comment: You could wrap class `A` in another class `B` with proper implementation and never use `A` directly. Question is: what do you intend a copy of `A` to do? Copy the content pointed out by `token`? Or both instance should share `token`?

Comment: Throw the library away because it is god awful. If you can modify it, just give it proper copy semantics

Comment: To echo @PasserBy, throw the library away, because if it's authors get this wrong, then who knows what else they have gotten wrong?

Comment: @PasserBy, come on, most of the libs I was working with (mostly some hardware API) are really badly designed, but if I threw away everything that is not well written I would have to write all the stuff on my own ...

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot modify `class A`, then you should avoid copying it. I think that the most safe way to do it is to allocate object of `class A` dynamically:

```
void anotherFunction(std::shared_ptr<A> aPtr)
{
    // please also note that in your case token is PRIVATE
    std::cout << aPtr->token << std::endl;
}

std::shared_ptr<A> aPtr(new A);
std::cout << aPtr->token << std::endl;
anotherFunction(aPtr);
```

Or if you insist on stack allocation, you should change `anotherFunction` signature to:

```
void anotherFunction(const A& a)
{
    std::cout << a.token << std::endl;
}
```

to pass your argument by const reference (avoid copy-constructor).

Now, if you CAN modify your `class A`, you should apply [the rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), because you have non-trivial destructor. The lazy way to do this would be to just declare other constructors as deleted (then, like in your example, you cannot copy your `A` object, but also you have a guarantee that no one will attempt to do so):

```
class A
{
    public:
    // for this example purpose I made token PUBLIC, but it is a bad idea in general
    char *token;
    A()
    {
        token = GetRandomToken();   // GetRandomToken will return a 'new Char' array
    }
    ~A()
    {
        if(token != NULL)
        {
            delete[] token;    // it is A's responsibility to delete the memory it created
            token = NULL;
        }
    }
    A(const A& other) = delete;
    A(A&& other) = delete;
};
```

Or, if you are not lazy, you can actually think about how to copy the memory from `token` pointer in one object to another object - it is up to you how you would implement it. That depends on the requirements and implementation of `GetRandomToken`.

Answer (score -1):

If your example is accurate then `class A` doesn't have a proper copy constructor and therefore deletes the token for both instances.
Which leads to a double delete because the pointer in the first instance didn't change.